# Why is the defaults command just returning the syntax?

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal, macos-catalina

I'm trying to run a terminal command from an application I'm working on in Xcode 11.4.

```
let path = "/usr/bin/defaults"
let arguments = ["defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock"]

let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
task.waitUntilExit()
```

That code is inside an `@IBAction` function which is connected to a button. I have testing that the button does actually call this as I replaced the above code with a simple `print("Hello world")` script and it worked great. However when I have the above code in the action and click it. The response is

```
Command line interface to a user's defaults.
Syntax:

'defaults' [-currentHost | -host <hostname>] followed by one of the following:

  read                                 shows all defaults
  read <domain>                        shows defaults for given domain
  read <domain> <key>                  shows defaults for given domain, key

  read-type <domain> <key>             shows the type for the given domain, key

  write <domain> <domain_rep>          writes domain (overwrites existing)
  write <domain> <key> <value>         writes key for domain

  rename <domain> <old_key> <new_key>  renames old_key to new_key

  delete <domain>                      deletes domain
  delete <domain> <key>                deletes key in domain

  import <domain> <path to plist>      writes the plist at path to domain
  import <domain> -                    writes a plist from stdin to domain
  export <domain> <path to plist>      saves domain as a binary plist to path
  export <domain> -                    writes domain as an xml plist to stdout
  domains                              lists all domains
  find <word>                          lists all entries containing word
  help                                 print this help

<domain> is ( <domain_name> | -app <application_name> | -globalDomain )
         or a path to a file omitting the '.plist' extension

<value> is one of:
  <value_rep>
  -string <string_value>
  -data <hex_digits>
  -int[eger] <integer_value>
  -float  <floating-point_value>
  -bool[ean] (true | false | yes | no)
  -date <date_rep>
  -array <value1> <value2> ...
  -array-add <value1> <value2> ...
  -dict <key1> <value1> <key2> <value2> ...
  -dict-add <key1> <value1> ...
```

If I run the above script `defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock` manually in terminal it works fine and resets all the docks settings.

**Other information**

1. The application is an agent as I am making it as a status/menu bar
   application
2. I am running Mac OS 10.15.4 Catalina
3. I also tried
   running `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add
   '{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'; killall Dock` which again worked in
   terminal but not when run from the app.
4. I have also tried to put those commands into a file inside the Xcode project such as `spacer.command` and then changing the `let arguments = ["defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock"]` line to `let arguments = ["spacer.command"]`. However it produces the same result.

My problem is that instead of running the full command, the swift code just seems to run the first word `defaults` because if you do that in terminal you get the same result. Why would it be doing this; and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Pretty sure that every "word" should be a separate argument. It's not one big argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help. I solved it by putting the shell command into a file in the project directory and then calling this code to run it...

```
let compiler = "/bin/sh"
let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "scriptName", withExtension: "sh")
let file = filePath!.path
let arguments = [file]
let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: compiler, arguments: arguments)

task.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: I hope you don't intend to release your app on the app store...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call multiple commands then you want to call the shell, not the `defaults` command directly.

Also:

- Separate-out each argument into a separate word in the array.
- I would probably use `&&` to invoke multiple commands.

Something like:

```
let path = "/bin/sh"
let arguments = ["/usr/bin/defaults", "delete", "com.apple.dock", "&&", "killall", "Dock"]

let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Alternatively call each command (`defaults` and `killall`) separarely.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your code above but got the following error `/usr/bin/defaults: /usr/bin/defaults: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: @myname you might have to pass `"sh"` as the first argument...  Otherwise it might be a case of using `-c` or `-e` or somesuch.

Comment: @myname it seems this should be something like: `let path = "/usr/bin/defaults"
let arguments = ["delete", "com.apple.dock", "&&", "killall", "Dock"]`